# Drupal 8 Commerce views filter Price

Tags: 8, commerce, views

I have a views with products and I want to sow products with price >= 100. I add Relationship 'Product variation'. All of my products are with one variation, so there shouldn't have duplication.
When I add Filter "Price" in popup no configuration options and filter no additional setting like in other numeric fields.

How I can get this filter to set >=?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this is in little custom module [here](https://github.com/svetlio/commerce_ext), 
in short: added new filter "Commerce Product variation Price", of course views should have relationship "Product variation".

Module contain also taxonomy term with depth filter (contextual is not work) for commerce_product, the same thing like on node.